# Regex in GA Filter view to show only specific URI

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to create a filtered view in Google Analytics  (GA) where I can see the results from if the "**uri contains**":

GA is configured if someone goes to xyz.com/state/city/landing-page they eventually get to: abc.d.efg.com/myfolder/index.htm

The **output** I am after in the filtered view is show me only if the uri's contain:

```
xyz.com/state/city/landing-page

and

abc.d.efg.com/myfolder/index.htm
```

I assume the settings below is what needs to be configured, but am not sure:

```
Custom>Advanced>
(select field) Field A -> Extract A
(select field) Field B -> Extract B
(select field)Output To -> Constructor
Field A Required (checked)
Override Output Field (checked)
```

How do I configure the [GA Filter Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh012.png) view setting above, with regex to only show if the contains those 2 uri's above?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing that as the target URLs are different domains (assuming xyz.com and efg.com both have different tracking codes).

Instead you can create a goal at supposed efg.com for a particular referrer path.